# Collections.singletonList with lambda expressions

Tags: java, lambda, collections, java-8, functional-programming

I have this piece of code that is working fine:

```
   return getHostimeta(time)
                        .stream()
                        .filter(e -> e.getPersonneId() == enfantId)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()).get(0);
```

I want to verify that the list has only 1 element:

```
return Collections.singletonList(getHostimeta(time)
        .stream()
        .filter(e -> e.getPersonneId() == enfantId)
        .collect(Collectors.toList())).get(0);
```

but I have this compilation error:

```
Required type:
IHostimeta

Provided:
List<Hostimeta>
```

Comment: _Collections.singletonList_ doesn't verify that. You can check the size of the list. And _Collections.singletonList_ doesn't take list it takes one element and create a list of that element. So currently it's returning _List<List<Hostimeta>>_ then get(0) means you are returning _List<Hostimeta>_

Comment: Generally, you should read [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#singletonList-T-) learn about its purpose, instead of making guesswork.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Collections.singletonList()` will not help you in any way with this problem.  The most plausible available solutions are

- to store the result of `collect(toList())` in a variable and, on a separate line, check that its size is 1
- to use another collector -- either inventing your own, or using [an existing one from a third party library](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/MoreCollectors.html#onlyElement--), since Java doesn't provide anything that can really help here out of he box
- to make this out of other collection operations, e.g.

  ```
  stream.reduce((a, b) -> { throw new IllegalStateException(); }).get()
  ```